# Fitting function to output from ecdf

Tags: r, ecdf

I would like to fit a function to the output from `ecdf`:

```
x<-rnorm(100)
z<-ecdf(x)
```

Please note that I do not want to fit a regular distribution but a generic function. My initial approach was to use `lm` but I cannot retrieve individual values of `z` for performing fit.

Comment: `ecdf(x)` will be a function that maps values to the range [0,1]. It is completely "non-parametric". It only depends on the data. Please explain what it is you desire that is not provided by that object.

Comment: I want to find a function that fits ecdf of a given data set (not the density(x) but ecdf(x)), then I will use this function in my further modelling

Comment: "Use it"? ... How? The ecdf function returns a function so what is not satisfying you about it's current value?

Comment: OP probably wants to obtain fit parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to do this with the built-in `ecdf` function either, but it's simple enough to write your own and then use `nls` to do the fitting. Here's the ECDF function:

```
ecdf2<-function(data) {
  sorted.data<-data[order(data)]
  return(data.frame('x'=sorted.data, 'y'=index(sorted.data)/length(sorted.data)))
}
```

Here's using that and then doing the fitting:

```
require("pracma")  #needed for erf()
e2<-ecdf2(x)
y<-e2$y
x<-e2$x
fit<-nls(y ~ 0.5 * (1 + erf((x - mu) / (sigma * sqrt(2)))))
```

If you look at `fit`, mu should be ~ 0 and sigma should be ~ 1, as expected.

Comment: which library is "index" found in?  My version of R (R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)) does not find function "index".

Comment: @EngrStudent: Ooops, that's in the `zoo` package. It's a very simple function though.

Comment: I'm trying to fit analytic in pdf with multiple components.  Thanks.